# Better way to get map of all pixels of an image with GD

Tags: php, gd

The following code uses the [SimpleImage library](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php)

I have a function that gets a pixel from an image:

```
function getPixel($x, $y) {

    $colors = imagecolorsforindex($this->image, imagecolorat($this->image, $x, $y));
    $n[0] = $colors['red'];
    $n[1] = $colors['green'];
    $n[2] = $colors['blue'];
    $str = "#";
    for($x=0;$x < 3; $x++){
        $n[$x] = intval($n[$x],10);
        if (is_nan($n[$x])) return "00";
        $n[$x] = max(0, min($n[$x],255));
        $bam = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        $str .= $bam{($n[$x]-$n[$x]%16)/16} . $bam{$n[$x]%16};
    }
    return $str; 
}
```

To get every pixel in an image, I use this loop:

```
$arr = [];
for($y = 0;$y < $image->getHeight(); $y++){
    $arr[$y] = [];
    for($x = 0; $x < $image->getWidth(); $x++){
        $arr[$y][$x] = $image->getPixel($x, $y);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this with GD and PHP?

EDIT

What I'm thinking of is some way to get the value of every pixel from GD without a PHP loop.

Comment: move `$bam` outside the loop?

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the pixel information?  Knowing that will drive the answers.

Comment: @charles - I'm using it to set the bgcolor of table cells

Comment: FYI all GD will do is call a loop to get the info. Just sayin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the ugly brute-force method, using imagecolorat() on every pixel. In my tests with large (6.5Mpixel) images, it's about 3.6sec, or about 1.1sec faster than the more elegant GD hack proposed by @cleong. It also has the advantage of brutal simplicity, and independence from the undocumented internal GD2 format.

```
$alphaLookup = array(
    0x00000000=>"\xff",0x01000000=>"\xfd",0x02000000=>"\xfb",0x03000000=>"\xf9",
    0x04000000=>"\xf7",0x05000000=>"\xf5",0x06000000=>"\xf3",0x07000000=>"\xf1",
    0x08000000=>"\xef",0x09000000=>"\xed",0x0a000000=>"\xeb",0x0b000000=>"\xe9",
    0x0c000000=>"\xe7",0x0d000000=>"\xe5",0x0e000000=>"\xe3",0x0f000000=>"\xe1",
    0x10000000=>"\xdf",0x11000000=>"\xdd",0x12000000=>"\xdb",0x13000000=>"\xd9",
    0x14000000=>"\xd7",0x15000000=>"\xd5",0x16000000=>"\xd3",0x17000000=>"\xd1",
    0x18000000=>"\xcf",0x19000000=>"\xcd",0x1a000000=>"\xcb",0x1b000000=>"\xc9",
    0x1c000000=>"\xc7",0x1d000000=>"\xc5",0x1e000000=>"\xc3",0x1f000000=>"\xc1",
    0x20000000=>"\xbf",0x21000000=>"\xbd",0x22000000=>"\xbb",0x23000000=>"\xb9",
    0x24000000=>"\xb7",0x25000000=>"\xb5",0x26000000=>"\xb3",0x27000000=>"\xb1",
    0x28000000=>"\xaf",0x29000000=>"\xad",0x2a000000=>"\xab",0x2b000000=>"\xa9",
    0x2c000000=>"\xa7",0x2d000000=>"\xa5",0x2e000000=>"\xa3",0x2f000000=>"\xa1",
    0x30000000=>"\x9f",0x31000000=>"\x9d",0x32000000=>"\x9b",0x33000000=>"\x99",
    0x34000000=>"\x97",0x35000000=>"\x95",0x36000000=>"\x93",0x37000000=>"\x91",
    0x38000000=>"\x8f",0x39000000=>"\x8d",0x3a000000=>"\x8b",0x3b000000=>"\x89",
    0x3c000000=>"\x87",0x3d000000=>"\x85",0x3e000000=>"\x83",0x3f000000=>"\x81",
    0x40000000=>"\x7f",0x41000000=>"\x7d",0x42000000=>"\x7b",0x43000000=>"\x79",
    0x44000000=>"\x77",0x45000000=>"\x75",0x46000000=>"\x73",0x47000000=>"\x71",
    0x48000000=>"\x6f",0x49000000=>"\x6d",0x4a000000=>"\x6b",0x4b000000=>"\x69",
    0x4c000000=>"\x67",0x4d000000=>"\x65",0x4e000000=>"\x63",0x4f000000=>"\x61",
    0x50000000=>"\x5f",0x51000000=>"\x5d",0x52000000=>"\x5b",0x53000000=>"\x59",
    0x54000000=>"\x57",0x55000000=>"\x55",0x56000000=>"\x53",0x57000000=>"\x51",
    0x58000000=>"\x4f",0x59000000=>"\x4d",0x5a000000=>"\x4b",0x5b000000=>"\x49",
    0x5c000000=>"\x47",0x5d000000=>"\x45",0x5e000000=>"\x43",0x5f000000=>"\x41",
    0x60000000=>"\x3f",0x61000000=>"\x3d",0x62000000=>"\x3b",0x63000000=>"\x39",
    0x64000000=>"\x37",0x65000000=>"\x35",0x66000000=>"\x33",0x67000000=>"\x31",
    0x68000000=>"\x2f",0x69000000=>"\x2d",0x6a000000=>"\x2b",0x6b000000=>"\x29",
    0x6c000000=>"\x27",0x6d000000=>"\x25",0x6e000000=>"\x23",0x6f000000=>"\x21",
    0x70000000=>"\x1f",0x71000000=>"\x1d",0x72000000=>"\x1b",0x73000000=>"\x19",
    0x74000000=>"\x17",0x75000000=>"\x15",0x76000000=>"\x13",0x77000000=>"\x11",
    0x78000000=>"\x0f",0x79000000=>"\x0d",0x7a000000=>"\x0b",0x7b000000=>"\x09",
    0x7c000000=>"\x07",0x7d000000=>"\x05",0x7e000000=>"\x03",0x7f000000=>"\x00"
); // Lookup table for chr(255-(($x >> 23) & 0x7f)).


$chr = array(
    "\x00","\x01","\x02","\x03","\x04","\x05","\x06","\x07","\x08","\x09","\x0A","\x0B","\x0C","\x0D","\x0E","\x0F",
    "\x10","\x11","\x12","\x13","\x14","\x15","\x16","\x17","\x18","\x19","\x1A","\x1B","\x1C","\x1D","\x1E","\x1F",
    "\x20","\x21","\x22","\x23","\x24","\x25","\x26","\x27","\x28","\x29","\x2A","\x2B","\x2C","\x2D","\x2E","\x2F",
    "\x30","\x31","\x32","\x33","\x34","\x35","\x36","\x37","\x38","\x39","\x3A","\x3B","\x3C","\x3D","\x3E","\x3F",
    "\x40","\x41","\x42","\x43","\x44","\x45","\x46","\x47","\x48","\x49","\x4A","\x4B","\x4C","\x4D","\x4E","\x4F",
    "\x50","\x51","\x52","\x53","\x54","\x55","\x56","\x57","\x58","\x59","\x5A","\x5B","\x5C","\x5D","\x5E","\x5F",
    "\x60","\x61","\x62","\x63","\x64","\x65","\x66","\x67","\x68","\x69","\x6A","\x6B","\x6C","\x6D","\x6E","\x6F",
    "\x70","\x71","\x72","\x73","\x74","\x75","\x76","\x77","\x78","\x79","\x7A","\x7B","\x7C","\x7D","\x7E","\x7F",
    "\x80","\x81","\x82","\x83","\x84","\x85","\x86","\x87","\x88","\x89","\x8A","\x8B","\x8C","\x8D","\x8E","\x8F",
    "\x90","\x91","\x92","\x93","\x94","\x95","\x96","\x97","\x98","\x99","\x9A","\x9B","\x9C","\x9D","\x9E","\x9F",
    "\xA0","\xA1","\xA2","\xA3","\xA4","\xA5","\xA6","\xA7","\xA8","\xA9","\xAA","\xAB","\xAC","\xAD","\xAE","\xAF",
    "\xB0","\xB1","\xB2","\xB3","\xB4","\xB5","\xB6","\xB7","\xB8","\xB9","\xBA","\xBB","\xBC","\xBD","\xBE","\xBF",
    "\xC0","\xC1","\xC2","\xC3","\xC4","\xC5","\xC6","\xC7","\xC8","\xC9","\xCA","\xCB","\xCC","\xCD","\xCE","\xCF",
    "\xD0","\xD1","\xD2","\xD3","\xD4","\xD5","\xD6","\xD7","\xD8","\xD9","\xDA","\xDB","\xDC","\xDD","\xDE","\xDF",
    "\xE0","\xE1","\xE2","\xE3","\xE4","\xE5","\xE6","\xE7","\xE8","\xE9","\xEA","\xEB","\xEC","\xED","\xEE","\xEF",
    "\xF0","\xF1","\xF2","\xF3","\xF4","\xF5","\xF6","\xF7","\xF8","\xF9","\xFA","\xFB","\xFC","\xFD","\xFE","\xFF",
); // Lookup for chr($x): much faster.



function lookUpImageBytes($canvas) {
    global $alphaLookup, $chr;
    $imageWidth = imagesx($canvas);
    $imageHeight = imagesy($canvas);
    // Faster than append, and >500mb more memory efficient for a 6.5MPx image!
    $imageData = str_repeat("\x00\x00\x00\x00", $imageWidth * $imageHeight);

    // Loop over each single pixel.
    $j = 0;
    for ($y = 0; $y < $imageHeight; $y++) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $imageWidth; $x++) {
            // Grab the pixel data.
            $argb = imagecolorat($canvas, $x, $y);
            $imageData[$j++] = $alphaLookup[$argb & 0x7f000000]; // A (convert from GD).
            // NB: three $chr arrays to replace the shifts WON'T improve speed.
            $imageData[$j++] = $chr[($argb >> 16) & 0xFF]; // R
            $imageData[$j++] = $chr[($argb >> 8) & 0xFF]; // G
            $imageData[$j++] = $chr[$argb & 0xFF]; // B
        }
    }
    return $imageData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer such an old question

Comment: Well, I needed the answer! And couldn't find it elsewhere, so... spent a chunk of the day writing various tests. Couldn't let that work go to waste! :)

Comment: Really weird thing I noticed: I tried optimizing further by making three copies of the $chr array, one for each byte of R, G, and B, so one was keyed with `0x01=>"\x01"`, one with `0x0100=>"\x01"`, and one `0x010000=>"\x01"`. I thought this would make it faster because I could omit the shifts. Instead, it went from 3.6 seconds up to 18 seconds! Even using NO lookup tables, and just calling `chr()`, was faster than that only about 7 seconds! I guess sparse array lookups are much, much slower than function calls...

Answer (score 2):

There is a faster way, but it's very tricky. What it involves is exporting the image to the GD2 format, then accessing the bytes directly. GD stores the pixels in chunks, so looping through the pixels is not straight forward. When done properly, it does yield much better performance since you're no longer incurring the overhead of calling a function on every pixel.

Here's some code that I have that I had written which capture the alpha channel from an image. As you can see, the loop isn't so terribly obvious because of chunking:

```
    imagesavealpha($image, true);
    ob_start();
    imagegd2($image);
    $gdRawData = ob_get_clean();

    $array = unpack("Nheader/nversion/nimageWidth/nimageHeight/nchunkSize/ndataFormat/ncolumnCount/nrowCount", $gdRawData);
    $imageWidth = $array['imageWidth'];
    $imageHeight = $array['imageHeight'];

    $chunkWidth = $chunkHeight = $array['chunkSize'];
    $columnCount = $array['columnCount'];
    $rowCount = $array['rowCount'];
    $lastColumnWidth = $imageWidth - ($columnCount - 1) * $chunkWidth;
    $lastRowHeight = $imageHeight - ($rowCount - 1) * $chunkHeight;

    static $transparencyToAlpha = array("\x7f" => "\x00", "\x7f" => "\x01", "\x7e" => "\x02", "\x7e" => "\x03", "\x7d" => "\x04", "\x7d" => "\x05", "\x7c" => "\x06", "\x7c" => "\x07", "\x7b" => "\x08", "\x7b" => "\x09", "\x7a" => "\x0a", "\x7a" => "\x0b", "\x79" => "\x0c", "\x79" => "\x0d", "\x78" => "\x0e", "\x78" => "\x0f", "\x77" => "\x10", "\x77" => "\x11", "\x76" => "\x12", "\x76" => "\x13", "\x75" => "\x14", "\x75" => "\x15", "\x74" => "\x16", "\x74" => "\x17", "\x73" => "\x18", "\x73" => "\x19", "\x72" => "\x1a", "\x72" => "\x1b", "\x71" => "\x1c", "\x71" => "\x1d", "\x70" => "\x1e", "\x70" => "\x1f", "\x6f" => "\x20", "\x6f" => "\x21", "\x6e" => "\x22", "\x6e" => "\x23", "\x6d" => "\x24", "\x6d" => "\x25", "\x6c" => "\x26", "\x6c" => "\x27", "\x6b" => "\x28", "\x6b" => "\x29", "\x6a" => "\x2a", "\x6a" => "\x2b", "\x69" => "\x2c", "\x69" => "\x2d", "\x68" => "\x2e", "\x68" => "\x2f", "\x67" => "\x30", "\x67" => "\x31", "\x66" => "\x32", "\x66" => "\x33", "\x65" => "\x34", "\x65" => "\x35", "\x64" => "\x36", "\x64" => "\x37", "\x63" => "\x38", "\x63" => "\x39", "\x62" => "\x3a", "\x62" => "\x3b", "\x61" => "\x3c", "\x61" => "\x3d", "\x60" => "\x3e", "\x60" => "\x3f", "\x5f" => "\x40", "\x5f" => "\x41", "\x5e" => "\x42", "\x5e" => "\x43", "\x5d" => "\x44", "\x5d" => "\x45", "\x5c" => "\x46", "\x5c" => "\x47", "\x5b" => "\x48", "\x5b" => "\x49", "\x5a" => "\x4a", "\x5a" => "\x4b", "\x59" => "\x4c", "\x59" => "\x4d", "\x58" => "\x4e", "\x58" => "\x4f", "\x57" => "\x50", "\x57" => "\x51", "\x56" => "\x52", "\x56" => "\x53", "\x55" => "\x54", "\x55" => "\x55", "\x54" => "\x56", "\x54" => "\x57", "\x53" => "\x58", "\x53" => "\x59", "\x52" => "\x5a", "\x52" => "\x5b", "\x51" => "\x5c", "\x51" => "\x5d", "\x50" => "\x5e", "\x50" => "\x5f", "\x4f" => "\x60", "\x4f" => "\x61", "\x4e" => "\x62", "\x4e" => "\x63", "\x4d" => "\x64", "\x4d" => "\x65", "\x4c" => "\x66", "\x4c" => "\x67", "\x4b" => "\x68", "\x4b" => "\x69", "\x4a" => "\x6a", "\x4a" => "\x6b", "\x49" => "\x6c", "\x49" => "\x6d", "\x48" => "\x6e", "\x48" => "\x6f", "\x47" => "\x70", "\x47" => "\x71", "\x46" => "\x72", "\x46" => "\x73", "\x45" => "\x74", "\x45" => "\x75", "\x44" => "\x76", "\x44" => "\x77", "\x43" => "\x78", "\x43" => "\x79", "\x42" => "\x7a", "\x42" => "\x7b", "\x41" => "\x7c", "\x41" => "\x7d", "\x40" => "\x7e", "\x40" => "\x7f", "\x3f" => "\x80", "\x3f" => "\x81", "\x3e" => "\x82", "\x3e" => "\x83", "\x3d" => "\x84", "\x3d" => "\x85", "\x3c" => "\x86", "\x3c" => "\x87", "\x3b" => "\x88", "\x3b" => "\x89", "\x3a" => "\x8a", "\x3a" => "\x8b", "\x39" => "\x8c", "\x39" => "\x8d", "\x38" => "\x8e", "\x38" => "\x8f", "\x37" => "\x90", "\x37" => "\x91", "\x36" => "\x92", "\x36" => "\x93", "\x35" => "\x94", "\x35" => "\x95", "\x34" => "\x96", "\x34" => "\x97", "\x33" => "\x98", "\x33" => "\x99", "\x32" => "\x9a", "\x32" => "\x9b", "\x31" => "\x9c", "\x31" => "\x9d", "\x30" => "\x9e", "\x30" => "\x9f", "\x2f" => "\xa0", "\x2f" => "\xa1", "\x2e" => "\xa2", "\x2e" => "\xa3", "\x2d" => "\xa4", "\x2d" => "\xa5", "\x2c" => "\xa6", "\x2c" => "\xa7", "\x2b" => "\xa8", "\x2b" => "\xa9", "\x2a" => "\xaa", "\x2a" => "\xab", "\x29" => "\xac", "\x29" => "\xad", "\x28" => "\xae", "\x28" => "\xaf", "\x27" => "\xb0", "\x27" => "\xb1", "\x26" => "\xb2", "\x26" => "\xb3", "\x25" => "\xb4", "\x25" => "\xb5", "\x24" => "\xb6", "\x24" => "\xb7", "\x23" => "\xb8", "\x23" => "\xb9", "\x22" => "\xba", "\x22" => "\xbb", "\x21" => "\xbc", "\x21" => "\xbd", "\x20" => "\xbe", "\x20" => "\xbf", "\x1f" => "\xc0", "\x1f" => "\xc1", "\x1e" => "\xc2", "\x1e" => "\xc3", "\x1d" => "\xc4", "\x1d" => "\xc5", "\x1c" => "\xc6", "\x1c" => "\xc7", "\x1b" => "\xc8", "\x1b" => "\xc9", "\x1a" => "\xca", "\x1a" => "\xcb", "\x19" => "\xcc", "\x19" => "\xcd", "\x18" => "\xce", "\x18" => "\xcf", "\x17" => "\xd0", "\x17" => "\xd1", "\x16" => "\xd2", "\x16" => "\xd3", "\x15" => "\xd4", "\x15" => "\xd5", "\x14" => "\xd6", "\x14" => "\xd7", "\x13" => "\xd8", "\x13" => "\xd9", "\x12" => "\xda", "\x12" => "\xdb", "\x11" => "\xdc", "\x11" => "\xdd", "\x10" => "\xde", "\x10" => "\xdf", "\x0f" => "\xe0", "\x0f" => "\xe1", "\x0e" => "\xe2", "\x0e" => "\xe3", "\x0d" => "\xe4", "\x0d" => "\xe5", "\x0c" => "\xe6", "\x0c" => "\xe7", "\x0b" => "\xe8", "\x0b" => "\xe9", "\x0a" => "\xea", "\x0a" => "\xeb", "\x09" => "\xec", "\x09" => "\xed", "\x08" => "\xee", "\x08" => "\xef", "\x07" => "\xf0", "\x07" => "\xf1", "\x06" => "\xf2", "\x06" => "\xf3", "\x05" => "\xf4", "\x05" => "\xf5", "\x04" => "\xf6", "\x04" => "\xf7", "\x03" => "\xf8", "\x03" => "\xf9", "\x02" => "\xfa", "\x02" => "\xfb", "\x01" => "\xfc", "\x01" => "\xfd", "\x00" => "\xfe", "\x00" => "\xff");

    $alphaDataSize = $imageWidth * $imageHeight;
    $alphaData = str_repeat("\x00", $alphaDataSize);

    // loop through all rows 
    for($r = 0, $j = 23; $r < $rowCount; $r++) {
        $rowHeight = ($r == $rowCount - 1) ? $lastRowHeight : $chunkHeight;
        // loop through chunks in each row
        for($c = 0; $c < $columnCount; $c++) {
            $columnWidth = ($c == $columnCount - 1) ? $lastColumnWidth : $chunkWidth;
            $firstY = $r * $chunkHeight;
            $lastY = $firstY + $rowHeight;
            // loop through scanlines in each chunk
            for($y = $firstY; $y < $lastY; $y++) {
                $firstX = $c * $chunkWidth;
                $firstAlphaPosition = $y * $imageWidth + $firstX;
                $lastAlphaPosition = $firstAlphaPosition + $columnWidth;
                // loop through each pixel in each chunk scanline
                for($i = $firstAlphaPosition; $i < $lastAlphaPosition; $i++, $j+= 4) {
                    $alphaData[$i] = $transparencyToAlpha[$gdRawData[$j]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Each pixel consists of four bytes: alpha, red, green, and blue. Here, I'm only capturing the first byte.

Comment: Holy crap! Is there a website I can go to to learn how to do this myself?

Comment: can you tell me where I can go to find out about this?

Comment: For anyone using this, you might be interested that the internal format of GD2 is ARGB, so the indexes you want will be the ones immediately following the 'a' values.
High bit of 'A' is reserved, hence the lookup table.
The lookup table above can be halved in size, since there are two values for each key: the second value will overwrite the first.
For a tiny bit more speed, you can move the calculations of firstY and firstX outwards by one level of looping. In fact... I'll edit this to answer the question and have these changes.

Comment: NB: even after speed tweaks, this method tests about 25% *slower* for me on Windows than brute force with lookup tables (see my answer). Maybe faster if extracting only alpha, or faster on some OSs? Test on your target machine and pick what works best for you.